# Is it ok to call try_recv() in a spinning loop?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I want to process messages received on a `tokio::mpsc::Receiver<T>` in the following way:

```rust
loop {
    match rx.try_recv() {
        Ok(msg) => {
            // add to buffer/queue but process all when buffer.len() = 100
            ...
        },
        Err(e) => {
            match e {
                TryRecvError::Empty => {
                    // if there are no more messages ready immediately, 
                    // drain the buffer/process all currently in queue
                    ...
                },
                _ => ()
            }
        },
    }
    // short sleep required here?
}
```

Is it necessary to insert a small sleep to prevent the thread spinning (if so how should I determine the duration)? Is there otherwise some oversight/improvement to this approach?

This is in an async context, in a tokio runtime.

People are suggesting using a blocking recv, but how can I then have the same behaviour? In particular, I wish to buffer messages being received until I have 100 messages buffered, at which point process all, **OR** if there are no new messages immediately on the receiver then process the messages in the buffer. How can you implement this with a blocking read?

Comment: Why? Why not use a blocking receive?

Comment: Is this in an async context?

Comment: No, It is going to hog your cpu. you will get TryRecvError::Empty repeatedly once the channel is empty.

Comment: Using sleep in your code is almost always bad practice (I cant think of any reason why would you do that)! DONT DO IT. unless you are doing something timer related. Or trying to work with some garbage logic written by someone else, who also wrote there code with similar sleep based logic. and now you are in a mess of sleep race condition. huh!!!!

Comment: Indeed. Sleeps in code are a code smell, and particularly so in networking code. They don't solve problems, they just mask them. In this case the sleep would be either too long, which would waste time, or too short, which would waste the CPU, or, very occasionally at best, the right length. By contrast a blocking read always blocks for the correct amount of time, by definition.

Comment: Point taken about sleep or no sleep both being suboptimal. But in particular, I don't know how to achieve the same functionality of processing messages as soon as possible *unless there are more to come in the channel straight way, in which case we add to buffer* **if instead using a blocking revc**...

Comment: If there are no additional messages waiting in the buffer, you will process just one and it will work. So why not just do it always and forget about batches? Blocking read-process one message-blocking read-process one message etc. Simple!

Comment: There is an inherent overhead on the processing call, which takes the same amount of time whether it's a single message or an aggregated sequence of messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like what you actually want here is to use `recv()` for the *first* item, then `try_recv()` for the following items until your buffer has 100 items or the read returns empty. Then you process the items, and go back to the blocking read.  For example:

```
const BATCH_SIZE: usize = 100;

let mut buffer = Vec::with_capacity(BATCH_SIZE);

loop {
    match rx.recv().await {
        Some(msg) => buffer.push(msg),
        None => break,
    };

    while buffer.len() < BATCH_SIZE {
        match rx.try_recv() {
            Ok(msg) => buffer.push(msg),

            // For both errors (Disconnected and Empty), the correct action
            // is to process the items.  If the error was Disconnected, on
            // the next iteration rx.recv().await will be None and we'll
            // break from the outer loop anyway.
            Err(_) => break,
        }
    }

    process_the_buffer(&buffer);
    buffer.clear();
}
```

Comment: Why? Why not use `recv()` for everything?

Comment: @user207421 Because it looks like OP wants to process in batches of _up to_ 100, but smaller batches are okay. So we block on the first item because there's nothing else to do, but if a follow-up recv would block because the receiver is empty, then we want to _immediately_ process the items we have in the buffer. (This is one of the use cases of `try_recv` and is perfectly legitimate.) Then we are back to receiving the first item, so we block again. The first two comments in their code spell this out, albeit imperfectly.

Comment: Now I could definitely see an argument for doing something like `tokio::time::timeout(Duration::from_secs(1), rx.recv()).await` instead to debounce the buffering, but this is still the same basic concept as my sample code.

Comment: Why not just put the try_recv loop in the awaited recv arm, to consume the queue up to desired size?

Comment: @StevenSpungin You certainly could do that, though I think that might hamper the readability of the code, at least for me. I find deeply-indented code harder to follow.

Comment: Waiting for 100 batches just adds latency. Why wouldn't you just process whatever arrives as fast as it arrives? This is all very over-thought.

Comment: @user207421 You've made the assumption that processing messages has a linear cost in terms of the number of messages, when in the domain it actually has a constant cost (imagine the argument to the process function is a vector of messages as opposed to a single message).

Comment: @jsstuball I would not waste your time arguing with this user. Based on the message on their profile, they seem to be the type of person who will perform an unusually intense amount of mental gymnastics to defend their position and downvote instead of considering for one moment that they could be wrong.